# Merging two cube meshes

Tags: mesh

Learning Blender: so I have a cube mesh in edit mode. I duplicated its vertices and my mesh is technically two cubes now:

[image]

It may be redundant, but I would like to combine the two cubes to end up with something like this:

[image]

---

I've searched for things like "merge two meshes" or "combine vertices". In general, the posts I find are:

> Use CTRL + J

But I feel this answers a different question. It just doesn't work.

> Select the vertices, then press X, and select dissolve.

Doesn't work - dissolve removes the geometry since these are two different meshes (and I think it is suppose to be used on a single mesh).

---

Note: No, I'm not trying to make a rectangular prism (I could simply translate the cube's face). It's just an example - I might want to do this with two spheres etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many, many ways of going about this.

Possibly the fastest for this particular case:

1. <kbd>W</kbd>*> Bridge edge loops*
2. Edge select mode (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>)
3. Deselect edge ring (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>)
4. <kbd>⌦ Delete</kbd>*> Delete edge loops*

[image]

For two spheres you might do something like this:

[image]

Comment: Step 2 can be made a little easier, instead of de-selecting all, then re-selecting 2 loops for removal. you can ring-loop-deselect. (3 steps into 1).

Comment: @ideasman42 Good point. Mind if I add that to the answer?

Comment: of course, no need to ask :), Suggest including written steps too, they're easier to read/edit then animated gif's

Comment: Thanks, this is so cool. How did you make those gifs?

Comment: @Voldemort I used [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) (running in wine under linux). I recognize you from scifi.SE! Nice to see you over here :)

Answer (score 3):

Another way to merge two cubes.

1. Select the face of the cube that you want to merge with the other cube.
2. Change snapping mode to *Edges* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Turn snapping on with <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>. (Both are also accessed in the 3D view header)
3. Move the face with <kbd>G</kbd>, constrain the movement along the axis (in your example the Y axis).
4. Select everything with <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>; then press <kbd>W</kbd> and choose *Remove Doubles*.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the boolean modifier:

Select one of the objects you want to merge, in the modifiers panel select boolean. 
Change the operation to union

Set "object" to the other object.

Apply the modifier

Comment: This does not create geometry between the two objects