# How do I make two objects into one?

Tags: modeling

I have two objects that I have already positioned into each other the way I'd like them to be. My question is how do I make them into one actual object, like they were made like that. Thank you.

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15712/merging-two-cube-meshes, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5871/how-do-i-join-several-objects-into-one, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29131/merging-2-objects-no-loose-parts

Comment: @cegaton Thank you both. Those helped. Sorry for this.

Comment: @Hotboy no need to apologize. As you know, some questions have been asked before. Instead of writing the same every time time we just point to an answer that has been accepted. Keep visiting the site and also use the search box at the top.